# k3s issues with lxe is throwing disk size and imagepulling error

Tags: kubernetes, containers, runtime, k3s, lxd

I have created a small cluster and followed [this](https://github.com/automaticserver/lxe/blob/master/doc/examples/multi-node-cluster-with-k3s.md) and it throws me some error mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/8695).
That problem aside i have copied my local lxc image from container. I have pushed that to my vm where the pod will be scheduled. The `lxc image list`  verify that the image is there but still when it tried to deploy my pod i get these errors.

```html
2m15s                   Normal    Scheduled                 Pod/lxc-deployment-54c4fc4d68-c52zh    Successfully assigned default/lxc-deployment-54c4fc4d68-c52zh to nodek2
113s (x11 over 51m)     Warning   InvalidDiskCapacity       Node/nodek2                            invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
113s (x10 over 46m)     Warning   ImageGCFailed             Node/nodek2                            invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem
108s (x4 over 2m15s)    Warning   ErrImageNeverPull         Pod/lxc-deployment-54c4fc4d68-c52zh    Container image "nginx-image" is not present with pull policy of Never
108s (x4 over 2m15s)    Warning   Failed                    Pod/lxc-deployment-54c4fc4d68-c52zh    Error: ErrImageNeverPull
```

My deployment is pretty straight forward.

```html
metadata:
  name: lxc-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lxc-container
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lxc-container
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: lxc-container
        image: nginx-image
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "echo 'Hello from Container $HOSTNAME'"]
      nodeSelector:
       containerruntime: lxd
      tolerations:
        - key: containerruntime
          operator: Exists
```

Comment: what is the output of the 'lxc image list'?

Answer (score 0):

Issues solved. The kubernetes can not read the lxc images directly via docker or containerd, you have to convert it to docker or you have to use lxe container runtime to use lxc images with k8s.